# Another Bootstrap Issue - Modals

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have gotten one modal to work, but I can't get multiple to work. Whenever I click on the second one, the page dims like it is going to popup, but nothing happens. However, the first one works perfectly. Here is a link to the entire file - -removed- and of course a link to the page - -removed- I have used the $('#sample').modal(options) on both (changing #sample of course) but the second one just refuses to work.
Thanks.

```
EDIT: Nevermind, I found the answer, I forgot to close a <div> tag.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have multiple definitions of

```
id="donate"
```

in your code. Try fixing this.

Comment: Ok, I removed that, but I still just get a page dim whenever I click the second Donate button. Now in the file there is only one id="donate"  but it still just makes a dim page when clicking the second one.

Comment: Okay, if thats not helping then you I have the feeling that the modal fires but the modals are hidden because the class "hide" is not removed from them. Try using jQuery to change this when the button is clicked.

Comment: Any idea on how I would go about doing that? Sorry, I am not very experienced in jQuery.